# Running a function every second in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to call a function every second in pinescript. This function can have an alert. So basically this script would fire an alert every second.

I have tried a `security` method but it doesn't work.

something like this:

```
oneSecondInterval() =>
    alert("1s alert")
    1 //just returning value 1 to fulffil the condition that expression in security must return a value.

myvar = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'1S',oneSecondInterval())
```

The above code only issues alert at start of the bar and not every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super unpractical and wouldn't even work.

If your script triggeres more than 15 alerts in 3 minutes, the alerts will automatically stop.

If you want to check if it is a new second, you should use a `varip` variable but still, your script will be executed on each new tick. If there is no trade activity, it might take a while.

Here is an idea for you:

```
varip last_second = second(timenow)

is_new_second = second(timenow) != last_second
last_second := is_new_second ? second(timenow) : last_second
```

Then use `is_new_second` as a condition to trigger your alert.

Answer (score 0):

To execute your script each second, you must have your chart in the 1 second timeframe.
I think this timeframe is not open to the tradingview free account.